# How can I replace one JPanel with another JPanel in the same position?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, layout-manager

I have a JFrame with about four frames. After a given action I want to replace one panel with another in  the same position. My method for switching them looks like this (the `this` object is a class which extends `JFrame`):

```
 public void switchPanel(){
    mainPanel.remove(introPanel);
    mainPanel.add(questionPanel);
    this.repaint();
 }
```

The original creation of the window looks like this:

```
 mainPanel.add(titlePanel);
 mainPanel.add(sidePanel);
 mainPanel.add(introPanel);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You ask:

> How can I replace one JPanel with another JPanel in the same position?

Very easily: use a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) as this tool was built for just this situation.

If you had the following constants:

```
public static final String INTRO_PANEL = "intro panel";
public static final String QUESTION_PANEL = "question panel";
```

and added your JPanel's like so

```
mainPanel.setLayout(cardLayout);
mainPanel.add(introPanel, INTRO_PANEL);
mainPanel.add(questionPanel, QUESTION_PANEL);

cardLayout.show(mainPanel, INTRO_PANEL);
```

Then you could swap JPanels with:

```
cardLayout.show(mainPanel, QUESTION_PANEL);
```

would be all that were needed to show the swap, assuming that QUESTION_PANEL is a String constant that was used when you added the questionPanel to the mainPanel, and that the mainPanel uses the CardLayout.

For example:

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SwapPanels extends JPanel {
   public static final String INTRO_PANEL = "intro panel";
   public static final String QUESTION_PANEL = "question panel";
   private static final int PREF_W = 500;
   private static final int PREF_H = 400;
   private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
   private JPanel introPanel;
   private JPanel questionPanel;
   private Random random = new Random();

   public SwapPanels() {
      introPanel = createPanel("Introduction");
      questionPanel = createPanel("Question");
      setLayout(cardLayout);
      add(introPanel, INTRO_PANEL);
      add(questionPanel, QUESTION_PANEL);

      int delay = 3 * 1000; // show intro for 3 seconds
      new Timer(delay, new ActionListener() {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cardLayout.show(SwapPanels.this, QUESTION_PANEL);
            ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
         }
      }).start();
   }

   private JPanel createPanel(String title) {
      int rgb = random.nextInt();
      Color color = new Color(rgb);
      JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
      panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(color, 60));
      panel.add(new JLabel(title));
      return panel;
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return super.getPreferredSize();
      }
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      SwapPanels mainPanel = new SwapPanels();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("SwapPanels");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: This is very interesting and I tested it out and it does indeed work. My Only issue is that I was using MiG Layout. I removed that layout from the main panel to test this but I have to redo a lot of the layout I had done. Could I wrap the panel I want to swap into a `CardLayout` and then add in custom panels which use MiG?

Comment: @eignhpants: There's no problem with using MigLayout, none at all. It's quite common to nest JPanels, each using their own layouts. You would just need one JPanel somewhere that uses CardLayout, that would hold the swapped components, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

after the remove method you have to run the validate method that's all. The code will be like this:

```
public void switchPanel(){
    mainPanel.remove(introPanel);
    mainPanel.add(questionPanel);
    mainPanel.validate();
}
```

I hope that helps. Salam