# Temporarly Cover JFrame with JPanel

Tags: java, swing, ribbon

I'm attempting to implement a cross platform swing ribbon control (like office '07+ ish) I have found this easy enough to do with JTabbedPane. I am however stumped on the back stage 'file' menu. What I really need to do is when file is selected on the JTabbedPane is cover the whole JFrame with a JPanel without destroying the JComponents underneath. Is their  a z-index property or something I could do this with?

Your document in 'Normal' word with its tabs ext
[image: Normal Word Image]

You click file word with its 'backstage' file menu (notice all previous ui components are hidden)
[image: Word side menu]

Comment: Perhaps you want to swap views with a CardLayout -- but I'm not yet sure. Could you please clarify your problem a bit? Images might help, and if you post any online, post an address to your image (not the web page it's on), and we can place the image for you.

Comment: Yes, swap views with a CardLayout. Google the tutorial which will explain all with sample code. Also have a look at [this similar question and its answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26170974/how-can-i-replace-one-jpanel-with-another-jpanel-in-the-same-position).

Comment: Thanks hadn't come across CardLayout before knowing me i'll find uses for it all over the place now!